# "No primary key" message during Add-Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, blazor-server-side

I made an ASP.NET Blazor Server Project.

I created a Model class, a Service class and a DbContext class.
I also created an SQL database and connected to it on appsettings.json and startup.cs.

Below is my code in Startup.cs under `IConfiguration Configuration { get; }`:

```
services.AddScoped<ClassNameService>();  //connect to business logic 
            #region Connection String   
            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseName"))); 
            #endregion
```

When I typed the below code in Package Manager Console:

`Add-Migration DatabaseName -Context DbContextName`
I got the below error message:

> The entity type 'DisplayFormatAttribute' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

The problem is the I **do** have a primary key in ModelName.cs:

```
public class ContactPerson 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string Designation { get; set; } 
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public PhoneAttribute Mobile { get; set; } 
    public PhoneAttribute Landline { get; set; } 
    public EmailAddressAttribute Email { get; set; } 
    public string Address { get; set; } 
}
```

**Id** is the primary key here.

Below is the DbContext and Service class code:

```
public class AppDBContext:DbContext 
    { 
        public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> options) : base(options) 
        { 
        } 
        public DbSet<ContactPerson> ContactPeople { get; set; } 
    }
```

```
public class ContactPersonService 
    { 
        #region Property   
        private readonly AppDBContext _appDBContext; 
        #endregion 

        #region Constructor   
        public ContactPersonService(AppDBContext appDBContext) 
        { 
            _appDBContext = appDBContext; 
        } 
        #endregion 

        #region Get List of ContactPeople   
        public async Task<List<ContactPerson>> GetAllContactPeopleAsync() 
        { 
            return await _appDBContext.ContactPeople.ToListAsync(); 
        } 
        #endregion 

        #region Insert ContactPerson   
        public async Task<bool> InsertContactPersonAsync(ContactPerson contactperson) 
        { 
            await _appDBContext.ContactPeople.AddAsync(contactperson); 
            await _appDBContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        #endregion 

        #region Get ContactPerson by Id   
        public async Task<ContactPerson> GetContactPersonAsync(int Id) 
        { 
            ContactPerson contactperson = await _appDBContext.ContactPeople.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id.Equals(Id)); 
            return contactperson; 
        } 
        #endregion 

        #region Update ContactPerson   
        public async Task<bool> UpdateContactPersonAsync(ContactPerson contactperson) 
        { 
            _appDBContext.ContactPeople.Update(contactperson); 
            await _appDBContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        #endregion 

        #region DeleteContactPerson   
        public async Task<bool> DeleteContactPersonAsync(ContactPerson contactperson) 
        { 
            _appDBContext.Remove(contactperson); 
            await _appDBContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        #endregion 
    }
```

So why am I getting this error message and how do I fix this?

Comment: What do you have only one table? why you decided that ContactPerson causes the error? I see you have PhoneAttribute  for example.  Is it an enum?

Comment: @Serge I will add more tables once this part works properly. I'm assuming the problem might be in ContactPerson but I'm not sure. PhoneAttribute is a class within the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.

Comment: if PhoneAttribute is a class then  ContactPerson  class needs to be fixed. This is a bug. Pls post the rest of the classes.

Comment: @Serge I posted it.

Comment: Thanks, but i was talking about classes.  Do you have only  public DbSet<ContactPerson> ContactPeople and nothing else in your dbcontext? Sorry but I will have to ask again is PhoneAttribute  an enum or a class?

Comment: It's good to read the error messages. In your case, it says "entity type '**DisplayFormatAttribute**'". Hence all the code you've posted is irrelevant. Somewhere else you are using `DisplayFormatAttribute` class as type of a property, thus letting EF Core think it is an entity class.

Comment: @Serge Yes, there is nothing else in that dbcontext. there is another auto generated file called ApplicationDbContext.cs which is used for the login feature. The definition of PhoneAttribute is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.phoneattribute?view=net-5.0. I added "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;" at the top of the code.

Comment: @IvanStoev I did not manually type the word "DisplayFormatAttribute" anywhere nor does it appear anywhere in the Solution.

Comment: Then it's probably a property of `PhoneAttribute` or `EmailAddressAttribute` classes. These classes are attributes (data annotations) and are not supposed to be used as data.

Comment: @IvanStoev So you suggest I replace them with int and string?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. Just saying that you should not use them. What is the correct type is up to you. But it should be some primitive type or custom class, but definitely **not** an attribute. For these two probably `string`

Answer (score 1):

Your class contains some invalid properties. You can't use data annotation attributes as the property types. As a first approach you can replace attributes with strings:

`````
public class ContactPerson 
    { 
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } 
        public string FirstName { get; set; } 
        public string LastName { get; set; } 
        public string Designation { get; set; } 
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        public string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; } 
        [Phone]
        public string LandlinePhoneNumber { get; set; } 
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; } 
        public string Address { get; set; } 
    }
````
or you can try this validation for the phones instead of above one
````
[Display(Name = "Your contact number :")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A phone number is required.")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number.")]
````
`````

Comment: I tried the first option and it works now. I was able to create the migration. Thanks